# PushSharp APNS error

Tags: apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I don't know what's happening but PushSharp is not working anymore. I just updated to MacOS Sierra, but I'd like to believe it's not related to that.

This is my implementation (it was working one week ago):

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(
            "cio_aps_development.p12",
            "",
            X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var config = new ApnsConfiguration(ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Sandbox, cert);

// Create a new broker
var apnsBroker = new ApnsServiceBroker(config);
```

This is the error:

```
2016-10-06 11:53:44.AM [ERROR] APNS-CLIENT[1]: Send Batch Error: Batch ID=1, Error=System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: Error while sending TLS Alert (Fatal:InternalError): System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0003a] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/RecordProtocol.cs:430 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult ar, System.Boolean ignoreEmpty) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslClientStream.cs:256 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x002c6] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslClientStream.cs:502 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00035] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslClientStream.cs:396 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslStreamBase.cs:101  ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: The socket is not connected. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The socket is not connected
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginSend (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags socket_flags, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00021] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:2564 
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginWrite (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x000b4] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/NetworkStream.cs:934 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginWrite (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x000f2] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/NetworkStream.cs:954 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.BeginSendRecord (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ContentType contentType, System.Byte[] recordData, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00026] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/RecordProtocol.cs:765 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendRecord (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ContentType contentType, System.Byte[] recordData) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/RecordProtocol.cs:786 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendAlert (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Alert alert) [0x00027] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/RecordProtocol.cs:633 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendAlert (System.Exception& ex) [0x00021] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/RecordProtocol.cs:598 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndRead (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00051] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslStreamBase.cs:883 
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00011] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/LegacySslStream.cs:475 
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/LegacySslStream.cs:445 
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.MonoSslStreamImpl.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MonoSslStreamImpl.cs:77 
  at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Security/SslStream.cs:147 
  at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection+<connect>d__25.MoveNext () [0x00211] in <1389cefdb7bb4d6c97d6126934847d24>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection+<SendBatch>d__21.MoveNext () [0x00255] in <1389cefdb7bb4d6c97d6126934847d24>:0 
2016-10-06 11:53:44.AM [INFO] APNS-Client[1]: Sent Batch, waiting for possible response...
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #11
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #14
Apple Notification Failed: ID=1, Code=ConnectionError
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!